# Cálculo de hora baseado em GMT e horário de verão

Tags: php, datetime

Tenho um problema onde preciso calcular o horário em um determinado local do mundo. O cálculo deve acontecer e a única informação que eu tenho em mãos é GMT do local. EX: -1, 2, -3, etc.

Criei uma classe para calcular as horas baseado no GMT.
Segue:

```
<?php
class Data{
     private $dateFormat;
     private $data;

public function __construct($dateFormat = "Y-m-d H:i:s e I") {
    $this->dateFormat = $dateFormat;
}

public function getHoraUsingGmt($gmt)
{  
    if($gmt < 0)
    {
        $segundos = ($gmt * 60 * 60) * -1;
        $this->data = gmdate($this->dateFormat, time() - $segundos);
    }
    elseif($gmt == 0)
    {
        $this->data = gmdate($this->dateFormat, time());
    }
    else{
        $segundos = $gmt * 60 * 60;
        $this->data = gmdate($this->dateFormat, time()+$segundos);
    }
    return $this->data;
}
}
?>
```

Se eu utilizar o método getHoraUsingGmt e passar um valor como por exemplo '-1' ou '-2' o horário correto é informado. Porém, existe alguma forma de eu calcular isto e saber se o GMT está ou não utilizando um horário de verão? E se sim, me informar o horário correto?

Por exemplo, o GMT de brasilia é -3 (quando não estamos em horário de verão). Porém agora estamos no horário de verão e ele é -2. Existe alguma função da classe DateTime do PHP para este cálculo?

Comment: Que eu saiba a classe DateTime do PHP já lida com o horário de verão (vou procurar uma referência e posto aqui). Também existem APIs que você pode consultar para obter essas informações, como https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/.

Comment: Eu pensei em criar uma tabela no banco de dados com todos os estados. Colocar um intervalo que definiria a data de inicio e fim de horário de verão (se houver) e o GMT nesse horário. Mas achei "gambiarra" demais isso.. rsrs

(isto para estado brasileiros é claro) Para outros locais do mundo não sei como iria fazer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Classe DateTime do php já lida com os problemas mencionados, basta passar um timezone que ela vai converter corretamente;

```
// Pega a data atual com base no horario de Sao Paulo
$dt = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
```

Caso você não possa utilizar a mesma recomendo usar as funções clássicas de date e timezone:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo'); // Seta a timezone
$horarioVerao = date('I', $timeStamp); // Retorna se está em horário de verao ou não;
```

O parametro I (maisculo i) retorna se está em horário de verão ou não;
Verifique a documentação das funções [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) e [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) para mais informações;

Comment: Então se eu usar: `$dt = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone(Europe/Paris'));` vai me retornar a hora em Europe/Paris  baseado no GMT0 de Greenwich, certo?

Comment: @lwb Isto mesmo, apenas deve tomar cuidado para deixar o timezone entre aspas, conforme meu exemplo;

Comment: Sim, apenas esqueci do por no meu exemplo. :) Vou fazer alguns testes aqui. Obrigado.

Comment: Fiz o seguinte teste: `<?php
 $dt = new DateTime('2014-11-12 14:29:28', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
 echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>` porém não importa qual timezone eu coloque sempre me retorna a mesma hora. Tenha que fazer mais alguma coisa? 
Usando o 'now' funciona bem, porém vou precisar converter também algumas horas salvas para o timezone especificado. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema.
Segue o código que usei na solução!

```
<?php
$data_inicio = '2014-11-12 15:01:01';
$original_timezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');

$datatime = new DateTime($data_inicio, $original_timezone);

$novo = new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo');
$datatime->setTimeZone($novo);

$output = $datatime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $output;
?>
```

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: OK, agradeço se sinalizar uma resposta como a solução do problema.